# Solving a PDE with sympy or matlab

Tags: python, matlab, sympy, equation, pde

i would like to know how to solve the following PDE with sympy or matlab

thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i just solved it with sympy

```
import sympy as sp

x1, x2 = sp.symbols('x1, x2')
f = sp.Function('f')
phi = f(x1, x2)
eq = phi.diff(x1) * sp.cos(x2) + phi.diff(x2)
print(sp.pdsolve(eq)) # f(x1, x2) == F(-x1 + sin(x2))
```